# Cannot use my old account

Tags: support, login, openid, user-accounts, facebook

I have been using Stack Overflow with my Facebook account. However I deleted my account. By chance my current computer still had the account on. So registered into Facebook again with different e-mail address and changed my e-mail address on Stack Overflow.

Now, when I clicked to log in with Facebook, it gave me another ID, I changed my e-mail into Gmail, still gave another ID. I tried forgot my password option and entered the e-mail address, it could not find any e-mail address in the system. So what should I do to retrieve my account?

Comment: If I read this correctly - you deleted your Facebook account so need a way to get into your SO account without using the Facebook login?

Answer (score 3):

Go [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge) and fill out the form where it says *"If you have lost access to your duplicate account"* and SE will merge them for you.  Be prepared to provide some information (like the email address you specified in the profile of the orphaned account) that proves the account is yours.